# MAPE (mean absolute percentage error ) measurement in python result in error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to measure MAPE (mean absolute percentage error ) value in my random forest code. The MAE value is 7.5. When I try to calculate MAPE, it outputs:

```
Accuracy: -inf %
```

Here is my code for calculating MAPE. How to make it work OR why is it not calculating a value.

```
mape = 100 * (errors / test_labels)
# Calculate and display accuracy
accuracy = 100 - np.mean(mape)
print('Accuracy:', round(accuracy, 2), '%.')
```

Here are the values:

```
 errors: array([ 2.165,  6.398,  2.814, ..., 21.268,  8.746, 11.63 ])
 test_labels: array([45, 47, 98, ..., 87, 47, 72])
```

These are types:

```
var1          int64
var2          int64
var3          float64
var4          int64
var6          float64
var7          int64
var1.         float64
dtype: object
```

Examples values, over 8000 entries

```
      var1  var2.   var3               var4     var5                var6    var7
"420823370" "183"   "2019-09-07 22:13:04"   "84"    "2019-09-07 22:12:46"   "72"    "00:00:18"
"420521201" "183"   "2019-09-07 17:43:03"   "84"    "2019-09-07 17:42:51"   "46"    "00:00:12"
"420219554" "183"   "2019-09-07 12:43:02"   "88"    "2019-09-07 12:42:39"   "72"    "00:00:23"
"419618820" "183"   "2019-09-07 02:43:01"   "92"    "2019-09-07 02:42:46"   "80"    "00:00:15"
"419618819" "183"   "2019-09-07 02:43:01"   "84"    "2019-09-07 02:42:46"   "80"    "00:00:15"
"417193989" "183"   "2019-09-05 10:42:52"   "82"    "2019-09-05 10:42:23"   "0" "00:00:29"
"416891691" "183"   "2019-09-05 05:42:51"   "78"    "2019-09-05 05:42:49"   "72"    "00:00:02"
"416587222" "183"   "2019-09-05 00:42:51"   "88"    "2019-09-05 00:42:35"   "99"    "00:00:16"
"416587223" "183"   "2019-09-05 00:42:51"   "82"    "2019-09-05 00:42:35"   "99"    "00:00:16"
"416587224" "183"   "2019-09-05 00:42:51"   "80"    "2019-09-05 00:42:35"   "99"    "00:00:16"

id:Big Int. ts_tuid: Big Int. rssi: numeric. batl: real. ts_diff:interval
```

Here is code example:

*load data from CSV*

```
model = (
    pd.read_csv("source.csv", parse_dates=['var3', 'var5'], date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
    .assign(
        rssi_ts=lambda x: x.loc[:, 'var3'].astype(int) / 10 ** 9,
        batl_ts=lambda x: x.loc[:, 'var5'].astype(int) / 10 ** 9,
        ts_diff=lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x.loc[:, 'ts_diff']).astype(int) / 10 ** 9
    )
)

# Labels are the values we want to predict
labels_b = np.array(halti['var4'])
# Remove the labels from the features
# axis 1 refers to the columns
features_r = halti.drop('var4', axis = 1)
features_r2 = list(features_r.columns) 
# Convert to numpy array
features_r = np.array(features_r)

# Using Skicit-learn to split data into training and testing sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# Split the data into training and testing sets
train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features_r, labels_b, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)

# Import the model we are using
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
# Instantiate model with 1000 decision trees
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = 42)
# Train the model on training data
rf.fit(train_features, train_labels);

# Use the forest's predict method on the test data
predictions = rf.predict(test_features)
# Calculate the absolute errors
errors = abs(predictions - test_labels)
# Print out the mean absolute error (mae)
print('Mean Absolute Error:', round(np.mean(errors), 2), 'degrees.')

mape = 100 * (errors / test_labels)
# Calculate and display accuracy
accuracy = 100 - np.mean(mape)
print('Accuracy:', round(accuracy, 2), '%.')
```

Comment: Kinda hard to fix your problem when we can't run your code. What are the inputs? Types and values please. Create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I added '

Comment: This does not help me much. I don't know the dtypes of the arrays, and I still can't run your code. Please show a small example that I can paste into my editor and actually run to reproduce your error.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I added the code and some example data. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because MAPE is undefined when your test label is 0, which is one of several [shortcomings of using MAPE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299712/what-are-the-shortcomings-of-the-mean-absolute-percentage-error-mape). If you replace `accuracy = 100 - np.mean(mape)` with `accuracy = 100 - np.mean(mape[np.isfinite(mape)])` you will get a more sensible number.

Comment: You could also add some small numerical constant epsilon to the denominator for numerical stability. Many algorithms in Keras and Tensorflow do this.

Answer (score 0):

This time output shows Inf in mape error measure. The reason behind it we have zeros in observed values. When the dependent variable can take zero as one of the outputs, we cannot use mape as error measure. In this case other error measures should be used.

refrence:`https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/390751_f6b763e827b24c9cb4406cd43129c8a9.html`